# What are the effective ways to wrap a pita?

Tags: pita

I love pitas, but I've never been able to wrap them properly. Whenever I attempt to wrap them they always come out in a crescent-moon shaped, making it a lot more difficult to eat, and the toppings being too spread out. I initially thought I was just putting too much into the pita wraps, but after some experimenting this doesn't appear to be the case.

The end result I'm looking for is something similiar to the picture below. Where the toppings are put inside the pita, and the pita is tightly wrapped, and each bite allows me to get a good mix of topping, instead of only getting one type of ingredient in each bite.

[image: http://whotalking.com/flickr/Pita+Pit]

What are the effective ways to wrap a pita?

*although written instructions would work, a video or written instructions making use of a diagram would be ideal*

Comment: I make pita wraps like my sushi rolls - thin lines of ingredients wrapped carefully with seaweed (in this case, pita bread) of appropriate and good quality. It may be the case you might be unevenly spreading out whatever you're putting in your wrap, or you may still be using too much for whatever your bread can handle.

Comment: I think you should rephrase your question to - What are the effective and presentable ways to wrap a pita. The issue should not be "proper" but "effective" and "presentable".

Comment: @BlessedGeek: Good point. Rephrased.

Comment: I'm confused by the picture -- are you using the pita as a pocket, or as a wrap?  (or as a pocket, then wrapping it in paper?)

Comment: @Joe: You use the pita as a pocket, and then you wrap it.

Answer (score 7):

Pita bread is a small "pocket" bread, they are not really designed for rolling. You normally slice the pocket open, and just stuff it. Like this

[image: pita bread pocket]

Some bakeries make large or jumbo pita bread, that are generally not useful as pocket breads. These can be folded into a cone by taking the left and right sides and pulling together making a cone shape, then wrap in paper to hold it together as required

[image: pita bread cone]

Also, you can get Lebanese style flat bread in large squares or circles. These are ideal for making wraps. Add filling in a line to one side of a square or in the middle of a circle. Then roll into a large burrito or Sushi like shape, wrap in paper if needed, slice as desired

[image: Lebanese flat bread wrap]